# Angularjs, RESTful API, preload multiple services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, angular-http

I'm new at angularjs and need some guidance on the best approach for my project.

Most of my code works, but i got into some issues where my code doesn't always work as expected.
Probably due to some race conditions with the webservices.
As the webservice is completely seperated from the angularjs application i have no ways to pre seed.

I use angular 1.5 with ui.router to handle routing and $http for requests.

1. When i open up my users page /app/users i use data-ng-init to make a $http.get and then ng-repeat on a table. This works, however i do have this small gap while the system retrieve the data.
2. When i click the details button i redirect to /app/users/:userId. However i need to fetch data json data on page load from multiple resources here, and from time to time this step doesn't publish the data. Seems like some sort of racecondition as i can see the data is being returned with a console.log on callback. I get no errors on console though.

I have tried a few solutions without finding any really good ones yet. As i'm new to angularjs i think i missed something simple and need a push in the right direction.

The fetching is made like this, so pretty simple stuff.:

```
ApiService.whoami().
    then(
        function successCallback(response){
            $scope.user = response.data.data;
            console.log(response);

        },
        function errorCallback(response) {
            SweetAlert.swal({
                title: "Data error",
                text: response.data.error.message,
                type: "warning",
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            });
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using $timeout to delay the callback to give it time to fetch the data

```
 then(
    function successCallback(response){ 
   $timeout(function() {
        $scope.user = response.data.data;
        console.log(response);
     }, 1000);
    },
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Comment: The issue seems to be the other way around. E.g. i have a select box which uses select2. If i load my data on /users and save it to $rootState and then switches to the /users/:userID page alle is good. If i refresh and data isn't present when the page renderes it dosn't work even when data has been retrieved.